# John the ripper not displaying cracked password

Tags: password-cracking, john-the-ripper

When using john to crack Windows LM hashes it says it has cracked the passwords but does not display anything. See image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8fGC.jpg

Comment: please do not post images of text: copy/paste the text in your question

Answer (score 4):

You're not seeing them because they're invisible. :)

aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee (LM) and 31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c59d7e0c089c0 (NTLM) correspond to an empty password.

[This blog post](https://hashcrack.org/page?n=20042015) explains in a little more detail, with command line examples to show how an empty password is hashed.

Comment: Also, my personal opinion: this question - about the expected output of a well-known security tool - is reasonable and topical for this SE.